# Using int variables inside of curly braces in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

I have a script that displays every file in a directory that has a filename containing 5 or less characters:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | egrep '^.{0,5}$'
```

Example directory:

```
foobar
foo
bar
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
```

But when I try to use a variable in place of 5 like seen below, I get no output. No error, so I'm assuming it's still looking for some kind of range. But just not 0-5.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i num=5
ls | egrep '^.{0,$num}$'
```

How do I use a variable inside on the curly braces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curly braces are not the issue here, it is the single quotes.  Use double quotes - variables inside `''` are not expanded by shell:

```
ls | egrep "^.{0,$num}$"
```

---

See also:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601)

Answer (score 1):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); just use a pattern that matches everything *except* names with 6 or more characters:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' !(??????*)
```

If you need a variable length pattern, build it up with a loop:

```
pat=; for ((i=0; i<=$num; i++)); do pat+=?; done
printf '%s\n' !($pat*)

# POSIX-compatible variant
i=0
pat=?
while [ "$i" < "$num" ]; do
  printf '%s\n' $pat
  pat+=?
done
```

Or, match *all* files and filter them using regular expression matching.

```
for f in *; do
    [[ $f =~ ^.{0,$num}$ ]] || continue
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/sh
FIVE=5
ls | egrep "^.{0,${FIVE}}$"
```

You just needed to use quotation mark when using variables.